# Linq to SQL using group By, and order by count

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, linq

This is mysql query:

```
SELECT count(PVersion), PVersion
  FROM [Products].[dbo].[Active_Details] 
group by PVersion 
order by count(PVersion);
```

What will be its  LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
var product = 
            from p in yourContext.Active_Details
            group p by p.PVersion into pgroup
            let count = pgroup.Count()
            orderby count
            select new { Count = count, PVersion = pgroup.Key };

SELECT count(ProductVersion), ProductVersion , ProductID , SubProductID 
FROM [do-not-delete-accounts].[dbo].[Activation_Details] 
group by ProductVersion,ProductID,SubProductID 
order by count(ProductVersion);

var query = 
            from p in yourContext.Activation_Details
            group p by new 
            { 
               ProductVersion = p.ProductVersion, 
               ProductID = p.ProductID,
               SubProductID = p.SubProductID 
            } 
            into pgroup
            let count = pgroup.Count()
            orderby count
            select new 
            { 
                Count = count, 
                ProductVersion = pgroup.Key.ProductVersion, 
                ProductID = pgroup.Key.ProductID,
                SubProductID = pgroup.Key.SubProductID  
            };
```

Comment: Thank u very much.
One more thing I want that
I also want to access the other columns of table like PID, SPID .
But this query does not work, How can I?

Comment: please add a comment instead of adding an answer. Youll have to show me the sql query you have in mind as what you asking may not be possible with aggregate functions.

Comment: This is MY SQL query:  SELECT count(ProductVersion), ProductVersion , ProductID , SubProductID
FROM [do-not-delete-accounts].[dbo].[Activation_Details] group by ProductVersion,ProductID,SubProductID order by count(ProductVersion);         what will be its Linq  to sql.

Comment: Ive updated my answer with your new question. Please mark it as accepted if this is good for you.

Answer (score 7):

Should be a group into:

```
var product = (
    from p in yourContext.Active_Details
    group p by p.PVersion into pgroup
    select new { VersionCount= pgroup.Count(), pgroup.Key }
).OrderBy(x=>x.VersionCount);
```

Here is a [MSDN Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747.aspx#countGrouped) with examples

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am not able to access this

Comment: question asked for order by as well, see my solution.