# how to order by count in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to execute this query in linq:

```
select count(cd.Type) as count, cdt.Id, cdt.Name from DocumentTypes as cdt
join Documents as cd
on cdt.Id = cd.Type
group by cd.Type, cdt.Id, cdt.Name
order by count desc
```

So far I am trying this:

```
var d = from cdt in context.DocumentTypes
    join cd in context.Documents on cdt.Id equals cd.Type into c
    from j in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group j by j.Id into gj
    orderby gj.Count()
    from sg in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new{ Id = sg.Id, Name = sg.Type};
```

But it's not working. I get the following error message:

> The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

I don't understand this error. Can anyone explain how to get the id and type ordered by the frequency the type is used?

Comment: Why do you have the line `from j in c.DefaultIfEmpty()` in there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812326/linq-to-sql-using-group-by-and-order-by-count
you should be able to distill your linq query from the answers